# Align cell height of the tabularx rows

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

The following latex code prints rows one at a time. However all the cells of the rows don't come out aligned. How can I fix it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\usepackage{tabularx}  

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
 \begin{tabularx}{3.50in}{lXX}
          \hline
          & Observation & Conclusion \\
          \hline  
          \uncover<2->{1.} & \uncover<2->{Observation 1 } & \uncover<2->{Conclusion 1} \\  
\uncover<3->{2.} & \uncover<3->{Observation 2} & \uncover<3->{Conclusion 2} \\  
        \end{tabularx}     
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

The output looks as follows :

[image]

As we can see cells in first column do not align with the rest of the rows. Will appreciate any input as to how to fix this.

Comment: Hi Sandeep- I removed the `align` tag as it's reserved for questions related to the environment provided by the `amsmath` package; I also removed the thanks and your signature, as it's always done automatically :)

Comment: This isn't really a fix, but if you use `\begin{tabularx}{3.50in}{XXX}` then the problem goes away... I don't know why this 'fixes' it though...

Comment: @cmhughes : Thanks for the prompt reply. Removing align is fine. I see that replacing l with X fixes the alignment. However now the width of the column becomes  too big. Is there anyway to set the width of a column to some fixed value?

Comment: you could use `\begin{tabularx}{3.50in}{p{1cm}XX}` and change the `1cm` to anything you like...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX is in a funny state at the start of table cells, it's best to avoid doing anything too clever there and beamer gradual reveals come in that category:-) `\leavevmode` gets you to a safer place.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\usepackage{times}    
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}   
\usepackage{exscale}  
\usepackage{booktabs, array}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{setspace}   
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage{listliketab}  

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{listliketab}   
    \storestyleof{itemize}   
    \tiny  

        \begin{tabularx}{3.50in}{lXX}
          \hline
          & Observation & Conclusion \\
           \hline  
\leavevmode\uncover<2->{1.} & \leavevmode\uncover<2->{Observation 1 } & \leavevmode\uncover<2->{Conclusion 1} \\  
\leavevmode\uncover<3->{2.} & \leavevmode\uncover<3->{Observation 2} & \leavevmode\uncover<3->{Conclusion 2} \\  
        \end{tabularx}     
    \end{listliketab}  

\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

For the first `l` column you're not leaving a mode at all (`\relax` would have done as well) you are just forcing TeX to stop looking for `\multicolumn` etc. In the `X` columns you need to stop the look-ahead for spanning columns but in addition you need to start the paragraph so the specials and any other nodes that beamer's magic drops at that position go at the start of the first line of the paragraph and not *before* the paragraph. You see the same with `\color` (which is why `\textcolor` starts with `\leavevmode` as does `\mbox` and most other latex commands of this sort.

Comment: +1 fantastic! Could you describe which modes we're leaving and entering?

Comment: @cmhughes, answer updated